# Authguard is preventing to navigate signup route. It always redirect to login page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, auth-guard

I have two separate pages for login and signup. I does'nt applied AuthGuard for these two pages. Even then when I navigate to signup it always redirect to login page.

I have tried to check current url in AuthGuard class to prevent redirection if url matches to signup page. But that didn't work for me.

These are my routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  //unauthorised routes
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginLayoutComponent,
    children : [
      {
        path: '',
        component: LoginComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'signup',
    component: LoginLayoutComponent,
    children : [
      {
        path: '',
        component: SignupComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'onboard',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: LoginLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: StepperComponent
      }
    ] 
  },
  //authorised routes
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children : [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent
      }
    ] 
  }
];
```

The expected behaviour is AuthGuard should not be fired where it is not applied.

Comment: Hello Supinder, here might be other factors that might be causing this and not only your routing setup. Could you please share a stackblitz link with your code so that I could troubleshoot further. Check what your auth guard redirects to. Also, I can see that you have added an Auth Guard to the root level, everything that is under `''` looks like is getting affected by the auth guard

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comment above, something like this might help

```
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent },
{ 
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard] 
},
```